# display mysql results on same page

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm used to working with C# and ASP.NET which automatically allows one to display database results immediately on the same page from which they were requested.

I am, however, now using PHP which I haven't coded in in years. I have the results popping up in a separate page because the form tag's 'action' option is set to that specific PHP page. I need these results to display, though, in the same page that I'm clicking the button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the 'action' tag to the current page, and move the POST request handling logic to that current page.

Comment: quick question.  how do I prevent the php logic from executing when the user visits the page for the first time?

Comment: @Josh: simply check if you have any data in $_POST[]

Comment: Check for your specific data in _POST. Actually, you may want to take this a step further, and also display the "first visit" page state in the case of a query returning an empty result set.